# Debugging Google Cloud Dataflow VM Instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Google Cloud Dataflow streaming job that have a growing system lag. Lag started when I deployed a new changes. Lag is gradually growing without subsiding. I see frequent GCs happening from the stackdriver logs which indicate inefficiency/bug introduced by newly deployed changes. I like to further debug this, what is the best way to debug JVM on Dataflow instances?

I have tried enabling Monitoring agent when launching the job, which gives me GC count/time which is not that useful to debug the source of issue.